# How to allow self-registration to join a specific Wordpress MU blog

Tags: blogs, wordpress

I have a Wordpress MU instance installed.

I allow self-registration, and self-creation of blogs.

I have a user who has created a blog for a Chemistry class.  He wants his 100 students to be able to self-register and become authors on this blog.

By default, when you follow the Wordpress MU register link, you are signing up for a site-wide account not for this specific blog.

How do I do this?  It would be very painful to have to add the 100 students one by one as the administrator.  Besides that, we don't actually have a list of the 100 email addresses.

I need a way that people can either request to become part of the blog, or automatically start contributing right away.

Comment: Anyone know a good forum ( other than http://mu.wordpress.org/forums/ ) to discuss WordPress MU problems?  I will award the bounty to someone who can point me to a good alternative WPMU community.

Comment: Hey Jeph,

I've just run into the same problem. What did you end up doing?

Comment: I never found a good answer.  Students self-register then the instructor has to add them to the blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try asking in the [BudyPress](http://buddypress.org/) forums, BudyPress is a social networking plugin for MU. (It might actually be closer to what your looking for)

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing is hiding registration on the main site and forwarding them to first find their blog and then register on the blog's website for the group for them to join.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings->General why not use the option that lets anyone register.  Then the students can each provide their email?

Comment: I am using Wordpress MU.  I already let everyone self-register.

What I need is a way for them to become a part of a single blog.  If all 100 students self-register, it is still a manual process to add each User to the Chemistry Blog.

Answer (score 0):

Then what about the Tools->Import->WordPress facility?  First do Tools->Export and look at how the file is structured, then create your own XML file with just your users, then do the Tools->Import->WordPress thing.

Comment: Why should I export and import the whole blog?  That doesn't really help anyways - I want people to sign up themselves.  I don't want to have to gather 100 email addresses from students and then import the whole blog.

Comment: Just to see if it was possible, I opened up an XML export file for my blog.  It does not contain any users.  Importing and Exporting is for posts and pages, not users.